# Use underlying primitive/collection of Type F#

Tags: types, f#

Learning F# at the moment and making a small game/script to try a bit of domain modeling etc.

I am somewhat familiar with map etc to 'elevated world', but fail to see how I could do anything atm.

My problem is I modeled the game using types, now I need to access/use a list that is created as a type. But I am not able to deconstruct it in any way. Some of the expected types have single or multiple backticks. These are generics right? But why are there so many different ones?

How to deconstruct/use these wrapped types ?

Main - see prints for errors:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let game = TTTGame.CreateGame ["John";"CPU"]
    
    game.Players
        |> printfn "%A" 
    // Players [Player ("John", Symbol "X"); Player ("CPU", Symbol "O")]
        
    game.Players
        |> List.iter (fun c-> printfn $"%A{c}")
    // Expecting a 'Players -> 'a' 
    // but given a ''b list -> unit'    
    // The type 'Players' does not match the type ''a list'
    
    // No output, not sure why:   
    let deconstructP x =
        match x with
        | Players p when List.length p = 2 -> List.iter (fun v -> printfn $"%A{v}")
        | _ -> (fun _ -> printfn "Not a valid list of players")
    
    deconstructP game.Players
    
    0
```

'Domain' model/types:

```
module TicTacToe =
    
    type Symbol = Symbol of string
    type Tile = Tile of Symbol * int
    type Board  = Board of Tile list
    
    type Player = Player of string * Symbol
    type Players = Players of Player list
    
    type Game = {
        Players:Players
        Board:Board
    }
    
    type MakeMove = Game * Tile * Player -> Game
```

Logic:

```
module TTTGame =
    open TicTacToe
    let private symbols = [Symbol"X";Symbol"O"]
    let private CreatePlayers (symbols:Symbol list) (playerNames:string list) =
       (playerNames , symbols)
       ||> List.map2 (fun x y -> Player(x,y))
       |> Players
       
    let private BuildPlayers = CreatePlayers symbols
    
    let private BuildBoard blank = Board([for xy in [1..10] do Tile(Symbol blank, xy)])
    
    let CreateGame players =
        BuildPlayers players
        |> fun p -> {
        Players=p
        Board=BuildBoard " "
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pattern match to get the list out of a `Player` instance:

```ml
let players = Players [Player ("John", Symbol "X"); Player ("CPU", Symbol "O")]

let (Players playersList) = players

playersList
|> List.iter (fun c-> printfn $"%A{c}")
```

You can also use the OCaml style `let ... in ...`:

```
let (Players playersList) = players in
  playersList
  |> List.iter (fun c-> printfn $"%A{c}")
```

However, I think that is less approachable for newcomers to F#.

Comment: Oh this is also a pattern match, I could only think of the match switches when thinking of pattern matching. Thanks, have to look at all types of pattern matching still.